# IllegalArgumentException: Invalid conditional statement inside expectation block

Tags: java, junit, jmockit, illegalargumentexception, expectations

I have a problem with an `Expectations` block I have written in my test case:

```
new Expectations() {
      {
        mFindHandlerMock.findAll((Model) any, (Set<Id>) any, false);
        if (!pWithRealData) {
          result = Collections.emptySet();
        } else {
          result = pAllData;
        }
        times = 1;

        Deencapsulation.invoke(mDb, "readSqlQuery", withAny(String.class));
        result = "select * from realdata";
        times = 1;
      }
    };
```

the test case crashes with:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid conditional statement inside expectation block
```

exactly here:

```
if (!pWithRealData) {
```

it's just a simple `boolean` that is `false` in this case.

I have absolutly no clue why the `exception` happens.
I already searched with google but found nothing helpful.

Could you help me?

Comment: Can you show how and where you declare and initialize `pWithRealData`?

Comment: It is a simple boolean. it can only be 0 or 1, false or true there is no initialization. If I would not pass the boolean I would get compilation errors. I pass false...

Comment: why are you putting one extra `{` Open and Close `}` Curly Braces ?? Is there any Need of That ??? is it a anonymous Initializer  Block  or using for any other purpose ??

Comment: the braces are necessary. without braces I would get "Syntax error on tokens, AnnotationName expected instead"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the JMockit release notes for version 1.14:

> Enhancement: Conditionals and loops will now trigger an exception when found inside an expectation recording block, to prevent API misuse and to encourage simpler tests. See issue #97.

The GitHub issues related to this:

- https://github.com/jmockit/jmockit1/issues/97
- https://github.com/jmockit/jmockit1/issues/123

In the one issue they state that:

> Yes, and this is as intended, to avoid tests getting too complicated when recording expectations. A full test was not shown, but it looks to me that recording the specific expectations directly would be better in this case.

In the JMockit [source](https://github.com/jmockit/jmockit1/blob/148226c4f389614653cdb35e03367838cdbd6952/main/src/mockit/internal/expectations/transformation/InvocationBlockModifier.java) you can see which other types of conditionals and loops will throw that exception.

In short, from JMockit 1.14 onwards you are not allowed to have conditionals (such as if statements) and loops in the Expectation block.